# Child component not rerendered on prop change

Tags: react-native, mobx, mobx-state-tree

In the following code, I expect `OfferList` to rerender when I add an offer item to the store. `OfferList` itself is not an observable, but the offer array is passed as a prop.

```
export const MerchantScreen: FC = observer(() => {
  const { merchantStore } = useStores()

  return (
    <View>
      <OfferList data={merchantStore.offers} />
      <View>
        <Button title={"New Offer"} onPress={() => merchantStore.addOffer()}/>
      </View>
    </View>
  )
})

export const OfferList: FC<OfferListProps> = ({ data }: OfferListProps) => {
  const renderItem = (offer: ListRenderItemInfo<any>) => {
    return (
      <Text>{offer.name}</Text>
    )
  }

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
    />
  )
}
```

I use Mobx State Tree. All `merchantStore.addOffer()` does for now is push another offer item into the array.

What I tried / findings:

When I read from the store in my `MerchantScreen`, e.g. by adding

```
<Text>{ merchantStore.offers.toString() }</Text>
```

, the `OfferList` will also update. I suspect that reading from the store directly in the parent component will force a rerender of the child component as well.

I stumbled upon some answers here that would indicate that a missing `key` attribute within the FlatList renderItems could be the issue. Tried using `key={item.id}` to no avail. Also, as you can see I use the keyExtractor prop of FlatList.

Another answers suggested introducing local state to the component like this:

```
export const OfferList: FC<OfferListProps> = ({ data }: OfferListProps) => {
  const [offers, setOfferss] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    setOffers(data)
  }, [data])
  
  const renderItem = (offer: ListRenderItemInfo<any>) => {
    return (
      <Text>{offer.name}</Text>
    )
  }

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={offers}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
    />
  )
}
```

This does not work and my gutfeeling is that this is not how it's done.

As you see my `MerchantScreen` parent component is an observable while my child component `OfferList` is not. From my expectation, the `observer` on my parent component should be enough. The parent component should already detect the change in the store and rerender. The child component in itself does not even use stores.

Overall, the problem at hand seems quite trivial so I guess I am just missing out on an important detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MobX only tracks data accessed for observer components if they are directly accessed by render, so if you want to react to each of the `offers` you need to access them somewhere. You sort of did when you tried `merchantStore.offers.toString()`, that's why it worked.

So first of all you need to make `OfferList` an `observer`.

But then you have `FlatList` which is native component and you can't make it an `observer`. What you can do is to access each `offers` item inside `OfferList` (just to subscribe for updates basically) like that `data={offers.slice()}` or even better with MobX helper method `toJS` `data={toJS(offers)}`

Depending on your use case you might also want to use `<Observer>` inside `renderItem` callback:

```
  const renderItem = (offer: ListRenderItemInfo<any>) => {
    return (
      <Observer>{() => <Text>{offer.name}</Text>}</Observer>
    )
  }
```